# Boost::asio and nested/recursive service.run()/run_one()

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

Is it possible that nested calls of io_service.run_one() is not a valid use of boost::asio.

For example I have a handler which is executed after something has been received on a socket. The io_service is running in another thread with io_service.run_one(). Hence in my opinion the io_service will stop after serving the receive handler.

Then in the receive handler I am executing io_service.run_one() again in order to send now something back over the socket. This means, that there is a nested/recursive call of io_service.run_one() method.

This behavior doesn't really work. I mean sometimes there is a block in the run_one() method which never returns. I couldn't also find any documentation handling about this particular case.

So, is it allowed to have recursive/nested io_service execution at all or is this not a well behavior?

P.S. io_service.reset() is used in front of every run_one() execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is neither intended use nor documented in asio, so it would seem like a safe assumption is: no, it's not valid.

Now, it may work, on some or all platforms, for now. That doesn't necessarily make it a good idea though.

Also, if you intend to not block inside your handlers, calling `run_one()`, you might want to consider `poll_one()`.

Either way, it definitely sounds suspicious to do this. Presumably you're assuming that a specific message is being dispatched, so that you can do some work immediately following it? I can only think of very contrived examples where it would be a safe assumption that two messages are back-to-back in the asio message queue.

Comment: In deed, I also think that this is not a safe way to use asio. I've changed now the full implementation to state based (like automata) and do not encounter any blocking problems anymore. It seems that in case when calling run_one() method from the handler might sometimes block forever.